# Using a regex for importing dimensions in a ppm file

Tags: java, regex, ppm

I’ve a problem finding the proper regex to read a ppm file dimensions. I don’t know if it’s because my regex is wrong or if I misuse the Pattern.compile method, but I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException. Below my regex and the code along to it. It reads the whole file since my regex always return null. 
Thanks.

```
package projet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Ppm extends File{
    private Dimensions d;
    private Color[][] p;
    public Ppm(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
}
public void read(){
    try {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(new FileReader(this.getPath()));
        while(s.findInLine(Pattern.compile("/^\\d* \\d*\\s$/")) == null && s.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ppm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Check filepath.");
    }
}
}
```

Here's my sample file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/z35dvi90zdfkws0/carte1.ppm?dl=0

EDIT :

I tried with a matcher, but it still doesn't work, following the corrected regex. Here's my code, it never matches the pattern...

```
public class Ppm extends File{
    private Dimensions d;
    private Color[][] p;
    public Ppm(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
        d=new Dimensions(0, 0);
    }
    public void read(){
        try {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(new FileReader(this.getPath()));
            Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^\\d+ \\d+\\s$");
            Matcher m;
            while(s.hasNext()){
                m=p.matcher(s.nextLine());
                if(m.matches()){
                    System.out.println("Found");
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("W : "+d.getWidth()+" H: "+d.getHeight());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ppm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Check filepath.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking for `hasNext()` and printing `nextLine?`

Comment: It's for sure problem with Scanner. Moreover, there is no need to create Pattern object for every iteration, just create it once and use  scanner.useDelimiter(yourPattern) . Can you paste a sample fragment because i opened the file which you posted and it contains lot's of number.

Comment: That's the sample I use. Cut it if you want a smaller fragment but it's a basic one. I really don't get why my code doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can never match.

```
Pattern.compile("/^\\d* \\d*\\s$/")
```

asks for a text has a slash *before* the beginning of the string and *after*  the end of the string. Unlike PHP, Java doesn't use regex delimiters. Try

```
Pattern.compile("^\\d* \\d*\\s$")
```

(and be aware that this also matches strings like `" 1 "` or `"1  "` or even `"  "`).

Comment: Thank you. I need to change the '*' by a '+' to scan for two numbers following each other right? Also I replaced the regex but it stills doesn't find the dimensions line and prints everything.